# How to place the Cross mark Button perfectly on a window

Tags: javascript, css

I have a close  mark Image (Cross Mark button) to close the pop up window .

```
<a href="javascript: window.close()"><img src="/" width="?" height="?" border="0" title="Click image to close this window"></a>
```

When i use this code the Cross Button Image is coming on the starting of the row , how can i place it at the end of the row ??

Please suggest

Comment: Why do you need such an image? There's already a button at the top of each window that provides exactly the same functionality.

Comment: @Marcel: maybe he means a lightbox, or modal or something, rather than an actual new browser window?

Comment: @David: I also considered that, but there's clearly a `javascript: window.close()` in his `href` attribute. I think it's not very likely that he (or a library) replaced that function to close a lightbox or such.

Comment: @Marcel, ah; yeah, there is that... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to set the container block to `position:relative` and then set the cross to `position:absolute` and modify the `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` to put it where you want it to go.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<a href="javascript: window.close()" class="cross-button"><img src="/" width="?" height="?" border="0" title="Click image to close this window"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { position:relative; }
.cross-button { position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add: `style="float:right"` to the element